# What is meant by "the source character newline?"

Tags: python

A particular definition in the python reference library (sub-section: string literals) is making me feel a lot of uncertainty.

`shortstringchar ::= <any source character except "\" or newline or the quote>`

What is meant by `newline` here? It definitely couldn't be `\n`, that's not just one source character, but two: `\` and `n`. Right?

I've been told that it's an invisible character, characterized by the split of a string into two physical lines when you press "enter/return" on your keyboard. For example,

1 `hello`
2 `world`

there is a newline character between `hello` and `world`.

How true is this? Could I get some more detail and maybe some source material that talks about the newline character?

Comment: newline (represented as `\n`) is a single character, not 2 different chars

Comment: If you search in your browser for "newline character", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A newline is the character between these two words:

`stack
overflow`

Answer (score 0):

`newline` is in fact a single character, a `control character`; its hexadecimal value is `0x0a`. The [way it usually is written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) is `\n`, where `\` "escapes" the following character, which is not a regular `n` but, in it's escaped context, the `newline`-character.

Put faith in good old [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Answer (score 0):

Actually (which is the case on windows) *newline* can consist of two characters: `\r\n`, the first of which has code 13 in decimal, the second is 10 in decimal. On linux it is just `\n`.

And yes, the wikipedia article linked in the other answer is pretty definitive on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it as an "invisible character, characterized by the split of the string". At the level of bytes, a newline is like any other character -- with the glitch that sometimes it'll be one byte, sometimes (i.e. on Windows) you'll see two.

But instead of being shown as black pixels on your screen (or as ink, if you're printing out), a newline causes a repositioning of where the next characters will be displayed. Other characters also have special meaning, e.g. Control-G used to ring the terminal bell (or later to flash the screen), certain sequences of characters clear the screen, etc. What's special about newlines is that they don't just affect display, they signal the division of text into logical records (lines) when it is read or written.

PS. To make it easy to write and see a newline like any other character, many programming languages and notations understand `\n` to represent a newline. But that's just a way to communicate "newline", it's not what files contain or programs manage.